# Which file gets executed when java program run through command prompt?

Tags: java, command-prompt

I am really curious about this question.

When we compile .java file using javac ie. `javac JavaFileName.java`, a `JavaFileName.class` file gets created. But when we run this java program by using java command on command prompt, we write `java JavaFileName`.

My question is which file is passed to `java` command when we run java program through command prompt?

If it uses `.class file` then why it gives error on `java JavaFileName.class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a file that you're nominating. Instead you're nominating a *class*, and Java will use the entries in the `classpath` to find this.

Your `classpath` will contain directories or .jar/.zips, and Java will search these in order.

Obviously for a directory, there's a mapping between the class nominated and the file. That applies too for the .jar/.zip. Java will look for the corresponding entry.

e.g.

```
   java a.b.c.D
```

will result in a search for the file or .jar entry `a/b/c/D.class`

Comment: I suspect your classpath specifies directories, in which case for 'A' it knows that it's looking for the corresponding file {dir}/A.class

Comment: it gives errors becaus it will search for the file at './fileName/class.class' :) the point in the fully qualified class means the package

Answer (score 1):

It's the .class that gets executed, you just don't write literally.

Comment: @SachinMhetre which is expected and fine. You do not need to specify it

Comment: If it uses .class file, then why it gives error on providing file with extension?

Comment: @SachinMhetre because this is how it is ment to work, this is how the engineers from sun decided that it should probably.

Comment: I am happy with your answer but not fully satisfied. Thanks Eugene

Answer (score 0):

It's not a file reference that is passed in command-line argument to java. It's the fully qualified class name (ie org.exemple.MyClass).
Java will look at the matching .class file in the classpath and call the main() method if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

It execute the *.class* file.
When you write

```
java MyClass
```

it will search in the folder where the command is executed the file *MyClass.class*, so when you write:

```
java my.package.MyClass
```

it will search for the file in the subfolders *./my/package/MyClass.class*, in the end when you write:

```
java MyClass.class
```

it will search for the file *./MyClass/class.class*

That's why you get the error.